# Connect server to different subnet

Tags: networking, router

On my home network I have my ISP modem, from that a LAN switch with other two routers connected.

If I have a server connected directly to the switch is there any way to make as if it was at all effects connected under one of the two routers running openwrt? Not discoverable from main network, protected by router firewall etc.

Final objective is to have a fileserver to which I can connect to from the outside using a vpn connection to my openwrt router and accessing the server.

The main network is to be considered hostile territory, many strangers access it. The switch and openwrt router are in a secure location.

Comment: Yes, there are several ways to do that. Which way is the best depends on details you didn't tell us. An easy way it to use VLAN (which means it's "not discoverable" from the main network, but a rogue computer on the main network could access it anyways by using the same VLAN). If you want protection from that, another way is an encrypted tunnel ("VPN"), and there are lots of alternatives for that.

Comment: Unfortunatelt this question is amost unanswerable as it depends at what level you are working and asks the wrong question. The answers will dependon your routers functionality, and the functionality of the server.  Your network, as described sounds badly engineered and the correct(but hard) solution is to reengineer it correctly for your usage case.

Comment: The main network is to be considered hostile territory, many strangers access it. The switch and openwrt router are in a secure location. VPN tunnel seems like a good secure idea!

What other details are useful I can provide?
The router's and server functionality I can adapt.
Why you say it's engineered badly?

Answer (score 0):

Very partial answer:

There's still not enough information. If the "main network" is considered "hostile", it would be a good idea to completely separate it from the rest.

For example similar to this:

```
       ISP router
       192.168.10.254
           |
       -------------------------------  192.168.10.*/24 network (LAN switch)
           |                    |
       192.168.10.1        192.168.10.2
       Other router        Server
       with firewall
       192.168.11.254
           |
       ................................ 192.168.11/*/24 network (WLAN, "main network")
           |
       192.168.11.x
       various WLAN clients
```

Note that you think in subnets, not in routers/switches.

This diagram will need to be changed to your needs (do both routers function as WLAN access points for the "main" network? Are there clients in the "main" network connected by LAN and not WLAN? Which routers exactly do you have? Do they contain an integrated LAN switch? Etc.)

So draw a picture like this, then refine it.